# BeautifulSoup: nested elements

Tags: python, python-3.x, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I would like to extract the Impact Factor (0.806) with BeautifulSoup from this HTML text (Springer journal descriptions):

```html
<div id="quick-facts-container" class="SideBox">
    <ul class="ListStack ListStack--float">
        <li>
            <span>Impact Factor</span>
            <span>0.806</span>
        </li>
        <li>
            <span>Available</span>
            <span>1996 - 2017</span>
        </li>
        <li>
            <span>Volumes</span>
            <span>22</span>
        </li>
        <li>
            <span>Issues</span>
            <span>265</span>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Because it's nested and I would like to get the content of the second `<span>` I don't know how to do it.

My python script is rather simple:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import urllib.request
r =urllib.request.urlopen('file:///197.html').read()
soup = BeautifulSoup(r, 'html.parser')
```

Comment: Please share the code you have tried.

Answer (score 0):

If you only want the text part of a document or tag, you can use the get_text() method. It returns all the text in a document or beneath a tag, as a single Unicode string:

```
In [6]: for li in soup.find('div', id='quick-facts-container').find_all('li'):
   ...:     print(li.get_text(strip=True))
   ...:     
Impact Factor0.806
Available1996 - 2017
```

Comment: Thanks, but I have several table elements (now added in my example).

Comment: @Morris Emacs check my update and feel free to accept my answer

Answer (score 0):

The following should work:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

r = urllib.request.urlopen('file:///197.html').read()
soup = BeautifulSoup(r, 'html.parser')

data = [i.text for i in soup.find(id='quick-facts-container').li.find_all('span')]
print("{} ({})".format(data[0], data[1]))
```

Which will display:

```
Impact Factor (0.806)
```

Comment: print "{} ({})".format(data[0], data[1]) throws "invalid syntax" for me (python 3.6.0)

Comment: For Python 3.x, the print needs to be as `print("{} ({})".format(data[0], data[1]))`